# update datetime from given datetime

Tags: javascript, datetime

I need to update every second a given datatime. 
It's not necessary a today date, that can be "October 11, 2017 08:01:29"

Something like this I suppose, but I lack of elements.

```
var dte = new Date("October 11, 2017 08:01:29");

setInterval('test()', 1000);
function test(){
    //update date "dte"
    console.log(dte)
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to update your date object every second, meaning that every iteration of the setInterval would increase the date object's second by one, correct?

In that case a solution could be something like this:

```
var dte = new Date("October 11, 2017 08:01:29");

setInterval('test()', 1000);
function test(){
    dte.setSeconds(dte.getSeconds() + 1);
    console.log(dte);
    // Should log 08:01:30 on first iteration...
}
```

Comment: Hi, no problem! And yes it will! You can test it out by setting the date to for example "October 11, 2017 23:59:00" and change the  amount of seconds to 30 to make the test faster :).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var dte = new Date("October 11, 2017 08:01:29").getTime();
setInterval('test()', 1000);
function test() {
    dte = dte + 1000;
    console.log(new Date(dte));
}
```

Comment: Yes you can use `setDate()` in same way.